# How to not parse out all the text from between tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing, regex-greedy

I tried to search Stackoverflow first to see if I could find a solution to what I'm trying to do with regex, but I'm not sure how to even ask this question. In fact, I'm not sure if I even phrased my question correctly...

Basically I'm trying to do what probably is a really simple regex search and omit.

```
                <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="country" id="chkCountry" checked="1" disabled="1"></td>
            <td><label for="chkCountry">Country</label></td>
            <td><label for="chkCountry">UNITED STATES</label></td>
        </tr>
```

I would like to parse out the text "UNITED STATES" from between these tags without also getting the text "Country":

`<td><label for="chkCountry">` and `</label></td>`

I have already set up my regex to do a match prefix and suffix but exclude them from capture by using the expressions:

```
    (?<=<td><label for="chkCountry">).*?(?=</label></td>)
```

and this will grab both of the words I mention above. How can I formulate this expression to only grab "UNITED STATES"?

The text "Country" is static and will always be there, but the text "UNITED STATES" is always different filling the text with other country names. So basically I want to scrape out the country that appears there.

I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If you know lookaround already, then negative lookahead shouldn't be too complicated for you?

Comment: i wouldn't bother doing all that with a regex. just match twice and take the second match.

Comment: I need to use regex because I'm using an old version of Winautomation that only gives me the option of regex or an exact word search which is not possible because the country changes. I'm new to regex and I'm currently studying lookahead and Negative Lookaround to try to figure this out.

Comment: which language/tool are you using.

Comment: Just curious, did you find anything on SO about parsing html with regex?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

`<[^<]+?>` <-- this is html tag regex

So, you just need to replace this regex `(<[^<]+?>)|(Country)` with empty string "" and that will leave you with only "UNITED STATES"

Comment: @Anirudh I'm using Winautomation 3 to the work but I'm testing it using Expresso

Comment: @harpo yes I found a lot about parsing html with regex on SO

Comment: so, `(<[^<]+?>)|(Country)` regex can take care any other than that "UNITED STATES" you are looking for right?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this entirely with a regex, try using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the `(?!)` construct):

```
(?<=<td><label for="chkCountry">)(?!Country).*?(?=</label></td>)
```

`(?!Country)` - this a negative lookahead. Like all lookaheads and lookbehinds, it's a zero-width assertion, which just means it matches a *position* between characters rather than a pattern of characters themselves.

So this matches "a position in the string that is not followed by `Country`". The regex engine had to *look ahead* to determine this.

Note that if you had a country named `CountryTown`, it wouldn't get matched by the full regex because the negative lookahead will fail.

Comment: with `.*` you would match the **last** `</label></td>`..with `.*?` it would match the first `</label></td>`

Comment: ah ok, thanks (i probably would have just done `[^<]+` instead)

Comment: @sgroves Thanks man, this works! Oddly it didn't work when I was testing in Expresso but when I tested in Winautomation it works perfectly. I'm assuming I'm not using Expresso correctly yet. Anyway thanks man...Please close this as resolved